# Closure: How can a reader effectively discern changes in a newer edition of the same book?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In response to [this comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58976/how-can-a-reader-effectively-discern-changes-in-a-newer-edition-of-the-same-book#comment138682_58976) which incorrectly describes my question, I have now changed https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/58976/13306 to clarify  that I am asking in general, for books that are not available computerised.

Is my question on topic now?

Comment: Note that there is no need to take this to Meta (yet). If you edit your question within a certain time after closure it will automatically be queued in the reopen queue and users with the close privilege can decide about exactly what you are asking here.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Bringing it to meta is entirely legitimate if the OP feels confused about the reasons for closure.

Comment: @jakebeal: Sure, but that did not seem to be the problem here.

Answer (score -2):

No, it's still a shopping question, and it's still not about academia.